# Set a CSS style for inner item

Tags: css

Could you tell me how to apply css to the below mentioned item ? Thanks.

This is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/14653/)**

**Note :** Just click the `Edit` button.After that it shows the date component.I need to reduce the height of that component.

[image]

I have tried as shown below.But it is not working :(

```
.editable-wrap editable-bsdate .editable-controls .input-group .form-control {
    height: 24px !important;
}
```

[image]

**Update :**

The `html` component is like this :

```
<td>
  <span editable-bsdate="comment.date" e-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" e-ng-click="vm.open($event,'$data')" e-is-open="vm.opened.$data" e-name="date" e-form="commentForm">
     {{ comment.date | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' }}
   </span>
 </td>
```

Comment: is it the `span` you want to set the height to?

Comment: @LGSon Actually not.Give me a few minutes to set up a Fiddle.After that I'll let you know.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding this classes it works.

The component has padding which affect its size as well as the set height.

```
/* input */
.input-group input {
  padding: 2px;
  height: 26px;
}

/* input calender button */
.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn, .input-group-btn:last-child>.btn-group {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/NfPcH/14654/)

Comment: Sorry,Please see the latest fiddle.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the dot in `editable-bsdate`

Should be this because `.editable-wrap` and `.editable-bsdate` are on the same element:

```
.editable-wrap.editable-bsdate .editable-controls .input-group .form-control {
    height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Regarding to your DOM inspector, this code should work. Do you test it ?

Comment: Yes,But not working ? Can you see the my update also.Thanks.

Comment: I have put a Fiddle.Please see that.Thanks.

Comment: Sorry,Please see the latest fiddle.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your solution also.I had a problem with my `less` file on the VS 2015.That is why this didn't work.I accepted the more complete solution for my task.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `>`selector like this

```
.editable-wrap.editable-bsdate > .editable-controls > .input-group > .form-control {
     height: 24px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I would add a class to the component html, like this:

```
<td>
  <span class="foo" editable-bsdate="comment.date" e-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" e-ng-click="vm.open($event,'$data')" e-is-open="vm.opened.$data" e-name="date" e-form="commentForm">
     {{ comment.date | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' }}
   </span>
</td>
```

and then use a simple CSS rule like:

```
span.foo{
  height:24px;
  //other rules here...
}
```

Comment: @Sampath what do you mean? The code in my answer doesn't work?

Comment: Yes,Please see my update also.This is a `html` component.I have shown above is the generated html code snippet for that component on the browser.Any thoughts ? Thanks.

Comment: @Sampath I edited my answer, let me know if it works now

Comment: No,That way it's not working.B'cos if you see the DOM inspector that component is having multiple items (2).One item is `date display` component and other one is `data selection` component.Any thoughts ? Thanks.

Comment: I have put a Fiddle.Please see that.Thanks.